# Attempting to run tomcat 7 and 6 on OSX yosemite

Tags: java, macos, tomcat, java-7, java-6

I have Tomcat 7 and Java 7 (1.7) installed  on osx Yosemite? I need to support very old applications as well.
*Should* I attempt to install Tomcat 6 and Java 6 along side Tomcat 7 and Java 7 on same local box?
Does Java 6 get placed 'locally' somewhere for Tomcat 6?
How does Java 6 get installed without affecting other applications?
How would Tomcat 6 get configuration to use local Java 6?
Best way to compile Java classes when using old Java 6?

Comment: See [Apache Tomcat: Which Version Do I Want?](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html), and Java 6+ with Tomcat 7 is fine. Tomcat 8 requires Java 7+.

Comment: Thanks. Added some clarification to problem above.

Comment: Java runtime is independent, and thus it could be installed to anywhere. A good practice might be to just take JDK zip, and extract it into a sub-directory of your Tomcat installation. That way you'd end up having a Tomcat installation which does not rely on the (globally installed) system java. It goes without saying that this also allows you to run multiple instances of Tomcat, each with a different version of Java runtime if you want to.

Comment: Install it to apache-tomcat-6.0.41/lib/ ?  I'll look more into not using globally installed java.